# Add jquery datepicker dynamically after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Upon a button click, I have some jquery that will add some html to the 'body' element.  In that html, I have a datepicker input field which refuses to appear when it should.

I use the ui-datepicker in several other spots in my app, and it works perfectly.

I have tried calling the datepicker when the document loads:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.my-datepicker-class').each ->
    input = $(this)
    input.datepicker()
```

and after the click event which adds the new html to the page:

```
$('.my-button').click ->
  $('body').ipadoverlay
    titleStyle: false
    contentWidth: 500
    topSpc: true
    content: $('#popup-for-' + thing_id).html()
  $('.my-datepicker-class').each ->
    input = $(this)
    input.datepicker()
```

But the picker refuses to show up.  My guess is that it has to do with when jquery builds and places the datepicker, but I really don't know.

Let me know if you have any ideas or could use more information.

**UPDATE**
I changed the way I call datepicker() so that it only applies to the element I want the datepicker attached to.

```
$('.ipadoverlay .date-picker').datepicker()
```

This eliminates the first issue with the .each =>.
Now it silently fails.  No error or warning.  The datepicker simply does not show up.

I am going to begin digging into jquery.ui.datepicker.js to see if I can figure out whats going on, but if you have any ideas why the datepicker fails to response, please let me know.

**UPDATE 2**
Ok, I got a step further.  The class 'hasDatepicker' was already attached to the element I want add the datepicker to (which means $('.date-picker').datepicker() was being called somewhere else, while the element was hidden and unused), but the datepicker didn't work.   I fixed this by removing the class from my element, and calling .datepicker() again

```
$('.ipadoverlay .date-picker').removeClass('hasDatepicker')
$('.ipadoverlay .date-picker').datepicker()
```

Now the datepicker shows up on click, but selecting a date doesn't do anything...  Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the fat arrow.  Your use of 'this' loses its context.

```
jQuery ->
  $('.my-datepicker-class').each => # <-- Fat arrow
    input = $(this)
    input.datepicker()
```

I'd explain, but [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org) does a better job than I ever could.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you @mattmc3 That certainly got me to the next step!  Now I am getting an error from jquery.ui.datepicker.js:145

`_attachDatepicker: function(target, settings) {
  var nodeName, inline, inst;
  nodeName = target.nodeName.toLowerCase();`

with error: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined_